# Where of my pattern is incorrect (Regex in Java)?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have some string data that have some pattern like this:
"0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9"

1. It has four parts.
2. Each part has three or four chars.
3. Each part begins with 0x.
4. Among the parts we have space.
5. Character just: A B C D E F
6. Numbers: 0-9

** i want to return this pattern as string ! how to return it ?
assume that sample input string that i get it, is :
"vhmbjfbfbbdbd This is part of my String 0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9 and rest afhahjbsdvbskb"
how to return this string after matching: "0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9"

```
String MP = MatchedPart(str).toString();
private static StringBuilder MatchedPart(String s) {
     List<String> sarr = Arrays.asList(s.split(" 0x[A-F0-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F0-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F0-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F0-9]{1,2}"));
     StringBuilder machpart = new StringBuilder();
     for(String t : sarr) {
         machpart = machpart.append(t) ;
     }
    return machpart ;
}
```

I write this function that gets a `string` and check pattern:

```
public static boolean test (String s) {

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" 0x[ABCDEF0-9] 0x[ABCDEF0-9] 0x[ABCDEF0-9] 0x[ABCDEF0-9]");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
  if (matcher.find()){
    return true; 
  } 
  return false; 
}
```

Comment: Only numbers form 1 to 9? Is it imposible to have a 0?

Comment: Check [this](http://ideone.com/t3iWhp), it might help.

Comment: @RubénJiménez , yes that right , i corrected my question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question just use like as below:

```
    public class PatternIncorrect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("------Test 1------------- ");
        System.out.println(test1("0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9"));
        System.out.println("------Test 2--------------");
        System.out.println(test2("0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9"));
        System.out.println("------Test 3--------------");
        List<String> test3 = test3("0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9asdasd0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9mfdskf0x4F 0xBB 0x74 0xA9");
        for(String t : test3) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }

    public static boolean test1(String str) {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(str.split(" "));
        boolean isMatch = true;
        String regEx = "0x[1-9][ABCDEF]|0x[ABCDEF][1-9]|0x[1-9][1-9]|0x[ABCDEF][ABCDEF]";
        for (String s : strings) {
            if (!s.matches(regEx)) {
                System.out.println(s);
                isMatch = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isMatch;
    }

    public static boolean test2(String s) {
        String regEx = "0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        return matcher.find();
    }

    public static List<String> test3(String s) {
        String regEx = "0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2}";
       return Arrays.asList(s.split(regEx));
    }
}
```

Source Code On [enter link description here](https://github.com/devbhuwan/stackoverflow-2015/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/developerbhuwan/java/july12/PatternIncorrect.java)

Comment: tanks for your answer , ho to return this pattern from that String input ?

Comment: how to get the mached part and return string ?

Comment: Simply pass user input into one of the method they return boolean value on the basis of pattern match.

Comment: my input string is unknown and i want to find this pattern in to it and after that return mached part as string ! after matching i need matched part ! did you get me ?

Comment: For eg. for android  :   1. EditText ed = (EditText) this.findView...Id(R.id_...); 2. String s = ed.getText(); 3. Copy above class in any package 4. Then use it like if(PatternIncorrect.test2(s)) { // go on code if match} else { // go for not match}

Comment: no ! i think you dont get me ! plz see my question again i add some example !

Comment: String match anywhere or at starting or at last

Comment: i need index of start and end match part ... , if my question is Confusing , say to me !

Comment: Brother finally i understand your question look in test3 method.

Comment: yes that's true , but how to set the matched part to textview (instead of System.out.println(s);) ?

Comment: TextView only not useful because you have no static list item in split string with pattern regex so use ListView pass split list as content of listview. One option for using text view concat all list string into a single string then put in to text view.

Comment: i think its possible ... i used this but it return some string that don matched with regex ! i add it on my question ! plz see and say why it return non matched string !

Comment: did you see my added function on top !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" 0x[ABCDEF1-9]{1,2} 0x[ABCDEF1-9]{1,2} 0x[ABCDEF1-9]{1,2} 0x[ABCDEF1-9]{1,2}");
```

If you want to be a bit more familiar with regex in Java, read : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Comment: Yeah, but as it was stated "each part have 3 or 4 char", I modified to make it work as expected

Comment: tanks for your answer , ho to return this pattern from that String input ?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression starts with a white space, which, from what I am seeing, your input string does not.

Also, and more importantly, according to your description you are attempting to match 3 or 4 characters, but according to your expression you are always expecting 3.

Replace `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" 0x[ABCDEF1-9] 0x[ABCDEF1-9] 0x[ABCDEF1-9] 0x[ABCDEF1-9]");` with `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2} 0x[A-F1-9]{1,2}");` and it should work.

For the record, `0x00` should also be a valid hexadecimal number, which your expression would seem to not consider as valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace [ABCDEF1-9] with the predefined pattern \p{XDigit}

another suggestion:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
int count = 0;
while(sc.hasNextInt(16)){
    sc.nextInt(16);
    count++;
}
return count == 4;
```